# Can't get TransmitReceive to work on STM32 nucleo board

Tags: stm32, spi, nucleo

I am using CubeMx and CubeIde with two nucleo-F042K6 boards.  I am fairly new to development on STM32 boards.

I am attempting to implement SPI communciation between the two boards.  I use a logic analyzer to monitor the communication signals.

I have set the one board up as a full duplex master,  the other as a full duplex slave.  The code on both machines is identical with the exception the the Master resets and sets the enable line.
I would tie enable low except the logic analyzer needs the toggle to decode the SPI signals.

As you will see I use #defines to select the operations I want to perform

When I set the Master to **TX__ONLY** and the Slave to **RX_ONLY** the results are acceptable but not exact; the first four characters received by the slave are zero ('\0') otherwise the message is complete.  I could live with that as long at it is repeatable but I don't think that is the way it would operate.

When I set the Master **RX_ONLY** and the Slave to **TX_ONLY**, the results are unacceptable. Master clocks out zeros ('\0') as is normal.
Unfortunately the Slave Message is a bunch of random characters.  I verified the the data I see on the MOSI line of the logic analyzer is received by the Master.

When I set ht MASTER to *TX_RX*_ and the Slave to **TX_RX** I can see the the Master message is complete on the logic Analyzer. Again there is only random data on the MISO data line.  The Slave message is more random characters.

I have looked at a number of sample codes and documentation.  They all suggest that this should be a simple, straight forward implementation so I must be missing something terribly simple.

I eventually want to implement SPI with DMA but if I have to get the simple implementation working first.

I would appreciate any suggestions and pointers.

Master code follows:

```
Master code follows:



/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
#define SPI_BUFSZ 50
char Spi_Tx_Buffer[SPI_BUFSZ];
char Spi_Rx_Buffer[SPI_BUFSZ];

int kntr1;
int kntr2;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
//#define __TX_RX__
#define __TX_RX__

  while (1)
  {
#ifdef __TX_RX__

            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED1_GPIO_Port,  LED1_Pin);
            memset(Spi_Tx_Buffer, 0, SPI_BUFSZ);
            memset(Spi_Rx_Buffer, 0, SPI_BUFSZ);
            sprintf(Spi_Tx_Buffer, "<M->S TxRx:%d>\r\n", kntr2++);

            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, RESET);

            HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, Spi_Tx_Buffer,
               Spi_Rx_Buffer, 20, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

           HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, SET);

#endif

#ifdef __TX_ONLY__

            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED1_GPIO_Port,  LED1_Pin);
            memset(Spi_Tx_Buffer, 0, SPI_BUFSZ);
            memset(Spi_Rx_Buffer, 0, SPI_BUFSZ);
            sprintf(Spi_Tx_Buffer, "<M->S Tx:%d>\r\n", kntr2++);

            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, RESET);

            HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, Spi_Tx_Buffer, 20, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, SET);

#endif


#ifdef __RX_ONLY__
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED1_GPIO_Port,  LED1_Pin);
            memset(Spi_Tx_Buffer, 0, SPI_BUFSZ);
            memset(Spi_Rx_Buffer, 0, SPI_BUFSZ);

            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, RESET);

            HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, Spi_Rx_Buffer, 20, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

           HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, SET);
#endif
           HAL_Delay(800);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI48;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief SPI1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 38400;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, SPI1_CS_Pin|t2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : SPI1_CS_Pin t2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI1_CS_Pin|t2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

I changed the clock frequency.

I placed separate transmit and receive function back to back. No joy.

I have used different nucleo boards.  Still the same results.

I have changed the Clock Polarity and Clock Phase. Same results.

Comment: "When I set the Master to TX__ONLY and the Slave to RX_ONLY the results are acceptable but not exact; the first four characters received by the slave are zero ('\0') otherwise the message is complete." This is not okay. This is undefined behavior. If you don't know why it happens, you have no idea how it may behave in other scenarios. Anything except the desired behavior is not OK. You need to address that as well.

Comment: Check out how your chip select pin operates. It can operate through SPI peripheral natively (hardware controlled), or it can be operated manually through GPIO toggle. You control it manually, but if SPI is configured with automatic chip select control, something like extra zeroes during sending is possible (something goes wrong with chip select and clock signal timings?)